# div positioning incorrect

Tags: html, css

as an excercise i decided to delve in to css layout styling and am already failing to see why my layout is not aligning correctly. also why is the container div only appearing when there some text in there. i thought it would display and grow based on the background property in css statement.  i have done screengrab to show problem. can someone show my error. thanks

screen grab: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/containergrabnew.png/

css

```
#container  {

  width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url(../images/container-bg.gif);
    background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
#containerLeft {

  width: 475px;

    float:left;
  background-image: url(../images/container-left-bg.gif);
    background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
#containerRight {

  width: 300px;

    float:right;
  background-image: url(../images/container-right-bg.gif);
    background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

html

```
<div id="container">
    This is the container
    <div id="containerLeft">
      This is the left container

    <div id="containerRight">
      This is the right container
    </div></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to have 3 <div> all horizontal to each other? as currently your divs will be nested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am already failing to see why my
>   layout is not aligning correctly

Your HTML is not nested correctly. Change it to this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="containerLeft">
      This is the left container
    </div>

    <div id="containerRight">
      This is the right container
    </div>
</div>
```

> also why is the container div only
>   appearing when there some text in
>   there. i thought it would display and
>   grow based on the background property
>   in css statement.

You need to clear your floated elements.

You can do this by adding `overflow: hidden` to `#container`.

You should read this article for more information: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

It discusses why this happens, various ways to fix it, and includes useful and relevant information about floats in general.

Comment: thank you thirtydot. very good site and article. i can see myself spending a bit if time there over the coming weeks :-)